# Android like loadingview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code to get the effect similar to that of the android  like progress:

[image: dialog]

```
-(void) showSpinner
{

    NSLog(@"as");
    loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 170, 170)];
    loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityView.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, activityView.bounds.size.width, activityView.bounds.size.height);
    [loadingView addSubview:activityView];

    loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 115, 130, 22)];
    loadingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    loadingLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    loadingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    loadingLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    [loadingView addSubview:loadingLabel];
    loadingView .center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) / 2);

    [self.statutoryTbl addSubview:loadingView];
    [activityView startAnimating];
}
```

The issue is that the `UILabel` appears below the spinner. I want it to be nearby spinner and the loadingview to be wide as android. What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Update the `xAxis` of `loadingLabel ` to 100 (or activityView.frame.size.width+ activityView.frame.origin.x+20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise your loadingLabel with this code:

```
loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([activityView frame].origin.x+[activityView frame].size.width+20, 10, [loadingView frame].size.width-([activityView frame].origin.x+[activityView frame].size.width+20)-10, [loadingView frame].size.height-20)];
```